# Angular2 bool scoping issue

Tags: angular, toggle, dropdown

I'm trying to make a Basic Select in Angular2 with angular-cli v1.0.0 and angular 2.4.10, but the problem is that the isOpen variable doesn't toggle when selecting an option, thus closing the menu.

```
BasicSelect.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'basic-select',
  templateUrl: './basic-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./basic-select.component.less']
})
export class BasicSelect implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  // Input is populated from an outside component after an http call
  @Input()
  selectOptions:Array<any>;
  // 
  @Input()
  selectedOption:BehaviorSubject<any>;

  public isOpen:boolean;

  public constructor() {
    this.isOpen = false;
  }
  //THIS WORKS
  public toggleDropdown():void {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
  //THIS DOESN'T WORK
  public selectOption(opt):void {
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.selectedOption.next(opt);
  }
}


BasicSelect.html
<div class="dropdown_container" (click)="toggleDropdown()" [ngClass]="{ 'show': isOpen }">
  <dl>
    <dt><span>{{selection}}</span></dt>
  </dl>
  <ul class="dropdown_items">
    <li *ngFor="let option of selectOptions" (click)="selectOption(option)">
      <span>{{option}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that if I click the dropdown container, works like a charm, but when actually selecting an option, the isOpen change is not seen by the component.

Comment: Once try using `event.stopPropagation()` inside `selectOption()` . I think it is the actual issue.

Comment: I tried doing that in the toggleDropdown function, and also force a detectChanges() from changeDetectorRef  but the result is the same.

Comment: Ok. I did that inside selectOption and now works. I don't understand why

Comment: Do  `event.stopPropagation()` in `selectOption()`. Once try it.

Comment: The event was propagated from the selectOption to the dropdown container, so the toggleDropdown() function was also called. 
Thanks for the quick solve !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
public selectOption(event, opt):void {
    event.stopPropagation()
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.selectedOption.next(opt);
  }
```

This is because, when you click on `li` element, you are triggering two click functions. One is on the `li` and second is on outer `div`. So, `event.stopPropagation()` will stop propagation of click event. There by only one click is triggered.

Read about it more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Hope it helps. :-)